# Export navigation menu

Tags: navigation, import, export

I want to export all navigation menu's from one site and import the menu's in another site.
I have tried to export the tables:

- `wp_posts`
- `wp_postmeta`
- `wp_terms`
- `wp_termmeta`
- `wp_term_relationships`

And import them in another database. This does not seem to work.
Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: WordPress has an Import/Export tool, but it doesnt works with nav menus only, you can try this [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/menu-exporter/) so the Menu option shows in Export

Comment: @DavidLee - Thanks for the suggestion, Although the plugin has not been updated in 6 years. It still does the job. Problem solved!

Comment: yeah, i had the same task before, let me put this in an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WordPress has an Import/Export tool, but it doesn't works with nav menus only, the "All Content" option will export the menus too, but with everything else that is in your site (including posts/pages in the trash) you can try this [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/menu-exporter/) so the Menu option shows in the Export page.

Comment: The plugin listed above has not been updated for 9 years. Here is a plugin [Export Import Menus](https://wordpress.org/plugins/export-import-menus/) (I have not yet tried it), that is more recent (as of this post, it was last updated 3 months ago, tested up to WP 5.4.4)

Comment: NOTE: it appears to import/export based on the post id. (menus and menu items are posts).If migrating to a different site, this may cause issues, but might be OK between LIVE-DEV sites SOMETIMES - if there will not be any post id collisions. It is a shame WP cannot natively export/import the menus separately.  It looked like parsing the xml file for menu items would be difficult. On such a large export file, it would at best be slow trying to edit mine.

Comment: Oh, I found another plugin, more recent (3 weeks ago, tested up to WP 5.6). Again, I have not yet tried it. [WPS Menu Exporter](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wps-menu-exporter/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tool from this site, https://caskispace.com/wp-export-file-parser/

It's not perfect but it does the job and can save a lot of time and effort. If it wasn't able to get the URL for a particular menu item it says so so you can update manually. As for the menu structure and everything it works really well.